# Set json attribute to nil within a jbuilder block

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, jbuilder

I have a scenario where I want to set a json attribute to nil if its object value is nil within a jbuilder block:

example of how I'm doing it now:
 
`unless obj.details.nil?
  json.details do |json|
    json.value1 obj.details.value1
    json.value2 obj.details.value2
  end
else
  json.details nil
end`

My question is there a cleaner way to do this so I don't have to use an unless/else

Comment: Did you find a cleaner approach?

Comment: nope never did.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a combination of `tap` and `json.nil!` for this.

```rb
json.details do
  obj.details&.tap do |details|
    json.value1 details.value1
    json.value2 details.value2
  end || json.nil!
end
```

**OR**

```rb
json.details do
  obj.details.tap do |details|
    return json.nil! if details.nil?

    json.value1 details.value1
    json.value2 details.value2
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks. Usefull response.